# Oracle ROWID values not working in hyperlink uisng PHP

Tags: php, oracle

**Using Oracle table in my page.**

When I click the Icon it should fetch the selected rowid and it's data.For that,I'm using the below code to pass the rowid dynamically

```
echo " <td><a  href='market_prices_detail.php?ROWID=" .$row["ROWID"]. "'></td>\n";
```

rowid getting the following error

[image]

error msg: Catchable fatal erro:Object of class OCI-LOB could not be converted to string

Comment: So what type does `$row["ROWID"]` have, _if_ the error really is thrown in _that_ line?

Comment: echo " <td><a  href='market_prices_detail.php?ROWID=" .$row["ROWID"]. "'></td>\n"; This is there in the line number 273 and the rowid is string datatype.

Comment: How do you create ``$row``? `OCI-Lob` certainly is NOT a string, so your data is not what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the rowid to string with the ROWIDTOCHAR(a.rowid) sql function